# Are all bounded linear operators including the ones that are Banach, also isometries?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, isometry, unbounded-operators

Are all bounded linear operators including Banach bounded linear operators, also isometries?

An isometry is a homeomorphism that preserves distance, i.e. only reorders the points.

May an unbounded linear operators, including those Banach and not banach be an isometry?

Comment: No. You will be absolutely clair on this after your studies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's plenty of bounded linear operators which are not isometries, such as scaling by a constant (different from $\pm 1$).

Unbounded operators cannot be isometries, since isometries are continuous while unbounded operators aren't.

Comment: May a linear functional be an isometry?

Comment: If the domain of the functional is a one dimensional space and the functional is multiplication by a unit, otherwise no

Comment: Is the lebesgue/rimeann/riemann-stijletes integral an isometry?

Comment: You should be able to answer that yourself. Is it injective fir example?

Comment: I think integration and differentiation are isomorphism, and isomorphism is equivalent to isometry.

Comment: Is bounded linear operator involving Banach space an isometry?